# Laravel 4 Virtual Host and mod rewrite setup

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, laravel

I've been trying for a few hours to install Laravel 4 and make the Virtual Hosts and Routing work but so far I've been unlucky. I'm mentioning that I'm doing this on a **Windows 7** machine and **WAMP**.

I'll describe what I've already done:

I've enabled rewrite_module.

Updated httpd-vhosts.conf with the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/laravel/public"
    ServerName laravel.dev
    ServerAlias www.laravel.dev
</VirtualHost>
```

Next, I've set up the `etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       laravel.dev
```

Also, the following lines are uncommented both in `wamp/../conf/httpd.conf` and in `wamp/.../conf/original/httpd.conf`:

```
LoadModule vhost_alias_module modules/mod_vhost_alias.so

Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

The content of my `.htaccess` is the following:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

**Yet,** when I go to http://laravel.dev I get an *Internal Server Error - The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.*.

If i remove the `.htaccess` file from the *public* folder, then I'll see the Laravel "You have arrived" message. If then, i create a route like this (within the *app\routes.php*):

```
Route::get('/newroute', function()
{
    return View::make('hello');
});
```

and then go to http://laravel.dev/newroute I'll end up with a *404 Not Found - The requested URL /newroute was not found on this server.*

I am seriously confused and have no idea how I can get past this. I mention (although i think it's clear) that I ran a `composer install` after cloning the project template, installing the dependencies.

Comment: So you have 2 htaccess files? What's the htaccess file in the "public" directory?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the htaccess file that you posted was in your `/public/` folder, then that's why you're getting a 500 internal server error. That htaccess file was made for the folder that the `/public/` folder *is in*. But since your public folder is the document root, you don't need it.

The htaccess file *in* the `/public/` folder should look like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

(for WAMP).

Answer (score 5):

Try turning on AllowOverride All on the directory by changing your VirtualHost to:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/laravel/public"
    ServerName laravel.dev
    ServerAlias www.laravel.dev
    <Directory "c:/wamp/www/laravel/public">
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Did you uncomment "LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so" in httpd.conf?

Comment: Yes, it is uncommented

Comment: On *nix systemns don't forget to change file permissions in order to apache can access them, like "sudo chown -R apache:apache path_to_your_project/" - used this in Fedora

Answer (score 0):

I have gone through the same issue and followed the all the treatments given above but virtual host can not be set.

When I inspected file `http.conf` then I found that inclusion of file `httpd-vhosts.conf` was commented as given below. Make sure to include `httpd-vhosts.conf` in httpd.conf.

`#Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`

I have removed the `#` comment. Restarted the wamp and it was working.

`Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`