# Laravel - Removing public folder

Tags: laravel, directory, public, httpd.conf

After editing my httpd.conf file to point directly to my www/laravelsite/public it returns a 403 forbidden. However, if i make it simply www/laravelsite i get the contents of the directory listed. Any advice?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What i thought was attributed to a laravel/apache issues appears to be directly an apache and .htaccess issue -- when i say 'issue' i mean my lack of understanding upon implementation. I solved this from trawling numerous other 403 forbidden queries and brute-forcing each solution.

Make the line below the first line of your .htaccess on the public directory:

Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch

Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a virtual host to rid the `public/` directory for the time being.

Once your application is in production you'll do the same thing if it already is in production you can do this now.

You'll also need to install and enable mod_rewrite for apache.

[Laravel 4 Virtual Host and mod rewrite setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19802286/laravel-4-virtual-host-and-mod-rewrite-setup)

Read the above answer to set up a virtual host and configure your apache web server.

Comment: mod_rewrite is enabled. I haven't used virtual hosts -- not sure why. The thing that is odd, is that when it's set to www/laravelsite the public folder isn't even in the directory listing? When it was in sub folders i could see it no problem.