# Laravel remote server error 500, site doesn't works

Tags: php, apache, laravel-4, web-deployment, remote-server

It's my first upload to a remote server of a Laravel site.

Local I have configured a vhost so my access to my site is like:

```
site.domain.com //it's pointing htdocs/laravel-proyect/public
```

I have uploaded my site to my remote server, then:

- Change permisions on storage and all its directories
- Change permisions to bootstrap
- Change configuration of app.php

  'url' => 'http://site.domain.com',
- Change configuration in database.app with new parameters (as well as in email.php)
- Load all tables and data in the data base

Then I try to load my site and get a 500 Internal Server Error

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

It works a little, I have this code in routes.php:

```
// Begins in the login view
Route::get('/', function()
{
    if (!Sentry::check()) {
        $data = array();
        if (Session::has('email')) {
            $data = array('email' => Session::get('email'));
        }

        return Redirect::route('login', $data);
    }
    else
        return Redirect::route('users');
});

/   ========================================
// LOGIN, LOGOUT AND ACTIVATION SECTION ==========
// // ============================================
// show the login page
Route::get(MyHelpers::textLang('login','routes'), array('as' => 'login', function()
{
    if (Sentry::check())return  Redirect::route('users');
    else {
        $rules = User::$rules_login;
        // show the login page (app/views/frontend/login.blade.php)
        return View::make('frontend.login', compact('rules'));
    }
```

So at first time mo url look like:

```
site.domain.com/entrar
```

'entrar', (login in spanish), y set by MyHelpers::textLang('login','routes'), access to my class MyHelpers and to lang files to translate 'login' in to 'entrar', but dont load the template.

Begins to :

- Read documentation, making some changes: deleting Multiviews from
  .htaccess (deprecated), adding RewriteBase to .htaccess too.
- Copy /public content to base dir and change paths in bootstrap/paths and
  in the index.php files.
- Reinstall in two remote servers to verify is not my provider failing (same error). Talking to my provider, supouse
  there are no errors on the server.
- I create a new htaccess in the base dir redirecting routes to /public.
- Try with php 5.4, 5.5 and 5.6

Actually my .htaccess is:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

And I have no more ideas and cant find other solutions as related here.

Any idea? Please, I'm getting crazy, on wensday I have to beguin a new proyect and still working with this one.

Thanks

Comment: start by looking at the error log for details about the 500. don't flail around trying different things until you KNOW what the problem is.

Comment: Thanx @Mark, I cant access server logs, my provider told me that it seems to be that server can't load some files.

Comment: it's ridiculous you can't access your own (error) logs, ask them to give you a copy paste of the error log or simply move to a more professional service. You will run into more 500's while developing, for a developer accessing those logs is critial. 500 errors are generated by simple typo's already.

Comment: I aks for them. Time ago I can access, now a cant access out of the public directiry, is a multidomain site with a poor config options (simple, but poor)

Comment: Works everythin if I delete de .htcaccess and get with 'site.com/index.php'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have to add

```
RewriteBase /
```

to the .htaccess

Comment: Mine too :D Thanks mate.

Answer (score 1):

I have a demo laravel application on heroku [Simple Blog](https://sweet-blog.herokuapp.com/).My .htaccess file is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
#other lines for gzip
```

It seems that there is no issue with your .htaccess file. It may be problem with you code logic. If you are getting no error with same code on localhost, then check your config again. For laravel 4, there is already a similar issue on stackoverflow [Laravel 4 Virtual Host and mod rewrite setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19802286/laravel-4-virtual-host-and-mod-rewrite-setup)

Note that laravel 5 (if you are using it) takes input (database connection and other setting) from .env file.

If you are still getting error then try to send simple response on index page like:

```
Route::get('/','basic configurations are correct');
```

and then make it complex step by step. It will help you in finding error.

Comment: Thanks @harish. I forgot to add that it works a little. I'll edit my post to add this. When access to the site, it begin to works, get into the routes file becouse muy '/' route redirect to /entrar (login in spanish), and the word 'entrar' it's in lang files and I get it with a personal helper static method in a helper class.

Comment: Is your login view (url site.domain.com/entrar) displaying properly without any error?

Comment: No, I get 500 error, but with this I see it properly: Route::get('/', function()
{
     if (Sentry::check())return  Redirect::route('users'); But Angular doesn't wokr (cookies policy), don't hide the message, and if a send the form gets again the 500 error
    else {
        $rules = User::$rules_login;
        // show the login page (app/views/frontend/login.blade.php)
        return View::make('frontend.login', compact('rules'));
    }
});

Comment: I have to go slowly ang see where crash, (have no time :P). thanks @harish Cache files could make this? May be it's looking for a cache file?

Comment: If cache is not an error then check these things: 1) I couldn't find this in laravel docs User::$rules_login; If it is your own variable then it must be static as you are calling it directly. 2) Try your application without MyHelpers (use direct url). It will tell that your helper is right or wrong. 3) If first two cases pass then your view is wrong. Then check your view file.

Comment: You should turn on the debugging until you are getting error. It will help you in finding place of error.

Comment: Yes debugging is on, I'm changing some thing slowly, if I find the proble may be be usefull for somebody too.

Comment: I have find what's wrong, but I don't know why. I cant set any template or call any controller method if I call it from '/', and they work. But if a call fron a url or I try to access /login, /register, anything, get error 500. Should be the htaccess, but I trying everything and I dont know wheres the matter. I have access too to nany data in data base calling it from '/' with Model::all()

Comment: If I don't find what's happening, I will ask for this issue again.

Comment: Check 1) Sentry is installed properly. Try to use Auth class. If it works then problem is with Sentry. 2) Check your helper and view. Can you share some code from helper and view files?

Comment: Sentry is working properly, as well I can load any view and use my helpers , any, but if I call them as '/' If I try to load any other path (loading index in route '/begin' for example) get the 500 error. So I sopuose its the .htaccess

Comment: ¡Works! Thanks. when I use it as '/index.php/anything' it works, I'd add 'RewriteBase /' to .htaccess and it works

Answer (score 0):

Answer from @kikerrobles really works.

your final `.htaccess` file should look like following

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>

        Options -MultiViews -Indexes

    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteBase /

    # Handle Authorization Header

    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .

    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$

    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```